# Small chest voice range A2-D4, can I learn to sing higher?

Tags: voice

After learning to sing for a while, my total vocal range is around A2-Bb5, can sometimes get a weak breathy G2 or strained C6 in falsetto.

What confuses me, is that my chest voice can't pass the wall at D4, no matter what I try, no progress for months. Seems I have an upper limit of a bass although I don't have the notes at the lower end.

C4 ist still easy, but D4 needs some push. If I don't push but thin out more, I break into head register around C#4. I feel like the break is a bit low to mix both registers, needs a super thin chest voice and hard to get chestiness into low head voice.

I can actually yell or twang like crazy up to G4, which feels and sounds really uncomfortable, it's probably not the key to unlock those notes.

So far I feel limited to low songs in chest voice and countertenor style classical singing.